# PHP array contain Items which every item is an array of key and values pairs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phpmyadmin

I'm a biggener in PHP. I have an array which is returned from database; It is a collection of data about items; every item has data in a form of key and value pairs
this is how my array looks

```
[{"item_id":"1","item_title":"Grand Nile Tower","item_title_ar":"\u062c\u0631\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0629","item_desc":"marvelous Hotel","item_desc_ar":"\u0641\u0646\u062f\u0642 \u0631\u0627\u0626\u0639","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"1","item_latitude":"25.248436","item_longitude":"45.252761","item_phone":"01069924166","item_site":"http:\/\/facebook.com","item_address":"This family-friendly hotel is located in the city center, within 1 mi (2 km) of Ethnological Museum and Egyptian Museum. ","item_address_ar":"\u064a\u0642\u0639 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0646\u062f\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0628 \u0644\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0626\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0641\u064a \u0648\u0633\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629\u060c \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0628\u0639\u062f 1 \u0645\u064a\u0644 (2 \u0643\u0645) \u0645\u0646 \u0645\u062a\u062d\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0631\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0634\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u062d\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0631\u064a.","item_email":"m.ezzat2020@yahoo.com","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/grand_otel.jpg","item_review":"3.5","id":"1","username":"m","comment":"mm","date":"20\/03\/2017","rate":"5"},{"item_id":"2","item_title":"Intercontinental Citystars","item_title_ar":"\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0643\u0648\u0646\u062a\u064a\u0646\u0646\u062a\u0627\u0644 \u0633\u064a\u062a\u064a \u0633\u062a\u0627\u0631\u0632 ","item_desc":"nice one","item_desc_ar":"\u0644\u0637\u064a\u0641","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"0","item_latitude":"31.248544","item_longitude":"32.279828","item_phone":"","item_site":"","item_address":"Omar Ibn El Khattab, Heliopolis, Nasr City, 11757 Cairo, Egypt","item_address_ar":"\u0639\u0645\u0631 \u0628\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0637\u0627\u0628 , \u0647\u064a\u0644\u0648\u0628\u0644\u064a\u0633 , \u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0646\u0635\u0631 , 11757 , \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0647 \u0645\u0635\u0631","item_email":"","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/intercontinental.jpg","item_review":"4","id":"11","username":"bnm","comment":"gogogo","date":"23\/3\/2017","rate":"5"}{"item_id":null,"item_title":"Pyramisa Downtown Residence","item_title_ar":"\u0628\u064a\u0631\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0632\u0627 \u0648\u0633\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0642\u0627\u0645\u0629","item_desc":"","item_desc_ar":"","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"0","item_latitude":"31.258426","item_longitude":"32.293099","item_phone":"","item_site":"","item_address":"Abi Emama Street, Dokki , Dokki, Cairo, Egypt","item_address_ar":"\u0623\u0628\u064a \u0625\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0642\u064a\u060c \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0642\u064a\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0629\u060c \u0645\u0635","item_email":"","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/parmisa.jpg","item_review":"0","id":null,"username":null,"comment":null,"date":null,"rate":null}]
```

so  i need your help to help me to understand how to filter or search inside this array

Comment: Do a json_decode($object,true) and search in that with in_array

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert this using `json_decode`.

Here is some code to demonstrate and also how to loop through the results.

Also, be aware that the JSON you gave in this question is invalid. You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to check. There was a missing comma between the hotels (just before **Pyramisa Downtown Residence**). I added the comma into the JSON used in my example ..

```
<?php

$str = '[{"item_id":"1","item_title":"Grand Nile Tower","item_title_ar":"\u062c\u0631\u0627\u0646\u062f \u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0629","item_desc":"marvelous Hotel","item_desc_ar":"\u0641\u0646\u062f\u0642 \u0631\u0627\u0626\u0639","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"1","item_latitude":"25.248436","item_longitude":"45.252761","item_phone":"01069924166","item_site":"http:\/\/facebook.com","item_address":"This family-friendly hotel is located in the city center, within 1 mi (2 km) of Ethnological Museum and Egyptian Museum. ","item_address_ar":"\u064a\u0642\u0639 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0646\u062f\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0633\u0628 \u0644\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0626\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0641\u064a \u0648\u0633\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629\u060c \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0628\u0639\u062f 1 \u0645\u064a\u0644 (2 \u0643\u0645) \u0645\u0646 \u0645\u062a\u062d\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0631\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0634\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u062d\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0631\u064a.","item_email":"m.ezzat2020@yahoo.com","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/grand_otel.jpg","item_review":"3.5","id":"1","username":"m","comment":"mm","date":"20\/03\/2017","rate":"5"},{"item_id":"2","item_title":"Intercontinental Citystars","item_title_ar":"\u0627\u0646\u062a\u0631\u0643\u0648\u0646\u062a\u064a\u0646\u0646\u062a\u0627\u0644 \u0633\u064a\u062a\u064a \u0633\u062a\u0627\u0631\u0632 ","item_desc":"nice one","item_desc_ar":"\u0644\u0637\u064a\u0641","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"0","item_latitude":"31.248544","item_longitude":"32.279828","item_phone":"","item_site":"","item_address":"Omar Ibn El Khattab, Heliopolis, Nasr City, 11757 Cairo, Egypt","item_address_ar":"\u0639\u0645\u0631 \u0628\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0637\u0627\u0628 , \u0647\u064a\u0644\u0648\u0628\u0644\u064a\u0633 , \u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0646\u0635\u0631 , 11757 , \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0647 \u0645\u0635\u0631","item_email":"","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/intercontinental.jpg","item_review":"4","id":"11","username":"bnm","comment":"gogogo","date":"23\/3\/2017","rate":"5"},{"item_id":null,"item_title":"Pyramisa Downtown Residence","item_title_ar":"\u0628\u064a\u0631\u0627\u0645\u064a\u0632\u0627 \u0648\u0633\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0642\u0627\u0645\u0629","item_desc":"","item_desc_ar":"","item_department_id":"1","item_views":"0","item_latitude":"31.258426","item_longitude":"32.293099","item_phone":"","item_site":"","item_address":"Abi Emama Street, Dokki , Dokki, Cairo, Egypt","item_address_ar":"\u0623\u0628\u064a \u0625\u0645\u0627\u0645 \u0634\u0627\u0631\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0642\u064a\u060c \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0642\u064a\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0647\u0631\u0629\u060c \u0645\u0635","item_email":"","item_image":"http:\/\/thabehaty.com\/ezzat\/portsaidy\/Shakraa\/images\/parmisa.jpg","item_review":"0","id":null,"username":null,"comment":null,"date":null,"rate":null}]';

$json = json_decode($str);

print_r($json);

foreach($json as $hotel) {
    echo $hotel->item_title;
    echo "\n";
}
```